# Standard Relay vs SSR vs TRIAC for Switching CFLs

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, triac

I'm confused weather I should go for a standard electromechanical relay (EMR) or a sold state relay (SSR) to switch CFLs @ 220V with 100W max load. This is for a commercial product with the following objectives:

1. Have at least 7 years of life (of continuous use)
2. Resilient to short-circuits at the outputs of it's switching device (SSR, EMR or TRIAC).

The main concern here is the failure of the device: SSR will provide an extremely long life (if other components are up to it) whereas a EMR will have a relatively shorter life-span. However, it seems EMRs are more rugged to a short-circuit (till the circuit breaker or fuse pops, at least). A failure mode of CFLs I've found is that they sometimes short-circuit - either the internal wiring insulation fails or some other type of fault due to sub-standard components).

I suppose the question becomes: how long can I expect an EMR with a resistive electrical contact life of 100,000 cycles to work if the relay is switched 10 times a day?

Alternate approach that I had in mind: use a large TRIAC (rated for 30+ amps continuous) and a resettable fuse, rated for 500 mA, in conjunction with it. The fuse interrupts the current flow thereby saving the TRIAC from damage. Since the TRIAC is a heavy-duty one it has a higher likelihood of surviving such a failure.

Will the TRIAC allow me to have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: Common SSR is just a TRIAC with optocoupler, so anything you said about TRIAC true for SSR too. (But SRR is more expensive than TRIAC with comparable preformance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be on the optimistic side to expect the resistive life to apply to a CCFL load, however an overrated (eg. 10A or 16A) mechanical relay with any kind of a rating for a tungsten load will probably last just fine with a 0.5A CCFL load.

If it was purely a resistive load you'd probably get in excess of 10^6 operations. Check the life curves in the relay datasheets.

Comment: Is the main problem the inrush current? One could limit that with an NTC? Also, most 10A relays seem to need a 100mA min @ 5VDC. load or more. It would work fine with a 100W CFL but wouldn't the life reduce if the load is less, say, 10W?

Comment: Yes, but it may not actually be a problem. Inductive loads are a lot nastier. You could easily perform tests. At one operation per 2 seconds you can get 10^5 operations in a couple of days, and I suggest you do this before thinking about NTCs.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question has no mentioning on space/weight restriction, how about using a circuit breaker with a suitably over rated relay (says, a few A is reasonably cost, weight and size)?

In case of external short, circuit breaker is faster than fuse so the short circuit overload energy is lower and stay within limit of a 'suitably over rated' relay.

As illustration (not that this particular one suits you), this randomly chosen relay has formal spec. on pulsed rating. "steady State Current Capability = 3.31 Amps. For pulse durations less than 0.5 s, it can carry up to 16.55A, factor of 5. For 50 ms, it can carry up to 33.1A, factor of 10."

[For 0.5 second pulse, current rating 5 times higher than continuous](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.teledynerelays.com%2Fpdf%2FEMR%2520FAQ.pdf&ei=TN7gU_GyFtKHuASM0oEo&usg=AFQjCNEHfpc6E9ceHghD1m_mIyz1DMvfUA&bvm=bv.72197243,d.c2E)

Answer (score 1):

10 cycles per day isn't much. Simple math says 100000 / 10 / 365 gives a life of 27 years for your EMR. Even if we take the 100K as a mean and assume failure can occur at 50%, you're still over your 10 years.

If it were me, I'd just go with the mechanical relay.

Comment: In terms of mechanical operations you are right. EMRs will last a life time if they are not cycling load. But if you are breaking load over and over the contacts will wear out much faster than the headling 'max # of operations'. It may still be acceptable, but it might be an order of magnitude fewer operations.

Comment: As a reference, see the DC switching cycles plot on page 2 of this data sheet: http://www.gigavac.com/pdf/ds/pp/gx11.pdf#page=2

Comment: But I agree with you - I am kind of old school, I like EMRs when space isn't a concern. The 'click' is satisfying feedback to know things are working.

Comment: @Nick Nice very specialized contactor. Good to know about.